# Can't run django project on mac imported from ubuntu

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, virtualenv

My colleague started a django project on Ubuntu. I want to run the same project on OS X Yosemite. We both use python3.4 and following packages:

- Django (1.8.2)
- Pillow (2.8.1)
- pip (7.0.3)
- setuptools (17.0)
- wheel (0.24.0)

And we both run project in virtual env.

When I cloned project, I used

> python manage.py syncdb

And I got following results:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/projectName/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/projectName/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/projectName/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/projectName/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/projectName/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 22, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/projectName/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/projectName/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 74, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/projectName/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/projectName/projectName/main/admin.py", line 3, in <module>
    from models import ContactLink, ContactPost, Personnel, WorkCategory, Service, Skill, Work, Customer
ImportError: No module named 'models'
```

I have no idea why this happens and used several methods described in this site and other sites.
What happened and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *should* have thrown an error on your Ubuntu install as well.

You need to change `line 3` of `projectName/main/admin.py` to:

```
from .models import ContactLink, ContactPost, Personnel, \
    WorkCategory, Service, Skill, Work, Customer
```

Notice the added dot `.` in the `from .models` part. The import should be relative (assuming all of these models exist in the same `main` app).